# SQL Server : decimal difference in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, decimal

I am trying to convert decimal hours difference in time however always round up causing problem.

```
declare @Accrued decimal(9,4) = 24.60
declare @Used decimal(9,4) = 23.5734
declare @Remaining decimal(9,2) = @Accrued -  @Used

declare @RoundAccrued decimal(9,2) = ceiling(@Accrued * 100) /  100
declare @RoundUsed decimal(9,2) =  ceiling(@Used * 100) /  100
declare @RoundRemaining decimal(9,2) =  ceiling(@Remaining * 100) /  100

declare @hrAcc int = @Accrued
select left(cast (@hrAcc as varchar), 4) + '.' + right('0' + cast((floor((@RoundAccrued * 60) % 60)) as varchar), 2) Accrued

declare @hrUsed int = @Used
select left(cast (@hrUsed as varchar), 4) + '.' + right('0' + cast((floor((@RoundUsed * 60) % 60)) as varchar), 2) Used
declare @hrRem int = @Remaining
select  left(cast (@hrRem as varchar), 4) + '.' + right('0' + cast((floor((@RoundRemaining * 60) % 60)) as varchar), 2) Remaining
```

Results

- Accrued: 24.36
- Used: 23.34
- Remaining: 1.01 (instead of 1.02)

It works perfectly on `Accrued` and `Used`, but whatever I did, it is still either one minute short or more than the different time.

Answer (score 1):

It's all happening because of using rounding, ceiling and floor.

[image: PLease see the details in the image below]

You can use something like below:

```
select convert(varchar(10), @hrAcc) + '.'+ right('0' + cast(cast((@Accrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as varchar),2)
select convert(varchar(10), @hrUsed) + '.'+ right('0' + cast(cast((@Used-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as varchar),2)
select cast((abs(cast(@hrAcc*60+cast((@Accrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as int) - cast(@hrUsed*60+cast((@Used-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as int)))/60 as varchar)
    +'.'
    + cast((abs(cast(@hrAcc*60+cast((@Accrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as int) - cast(@hrUsed*60+cast((@Used-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as int)))%60 as varchar)
```

---Test (Using rounded values instead of raw)

```
 declare @Accrued decimal(9,4) = 0.5333--106.325--106.325--51.2568--49.9217--106.325--49.9217--24.60
    declare @Used decimal(9,4) = 0.0333--87.885--87.885--49.9217--51.2568--87.88--51.2568--23.5734
    declare @Remaining decimal(9,4) = @Accrued -  @Used
declare @hrAcc int = @Accrued
declare @hrUsed int = @Used
declare @hrRem int = @Remaining 

declare @RoundAccrued decimal(9,4) = ceiling(@Accrued * 100) /  100
declare @RoundUsed decimal(9,4) =  ceiling(@Used * 100) /  100
declare @RoundRemaining decimal(9,4) =  ceiling(@Remaining * 100) /  100

select convert(varchar(10), @hrAcc) + '.'+ right('0' + cast(cast((@RoundAccrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as varchar),2) Accrued
select convert(varchar(10), @hrUsed) + '.'+ right('0' + cast(cast((@RoundUsed-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as varchar),2) Used
select cast((abs(cast(@hrAcc*60+cast((@RoundAccrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as int) - cast(@hrUsed*60+cast((@RoundUsed-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as int)))/60 as varchar)
    +'.'
    + cast((abs(cast(@hrAcc*60+cast((@RoundAccrued-@hrAcc)*60 as int) as int) - cast(@hrUsed*60+cast((@RoundUsed-@hrUsed)*60 as int) as int)))%60 as varchar) Remaining
```

Comment: I have tried without ceiling or floor but the result is same.

Comment: it fails when it goes negative Accrued: 49.9217 and Used: 51.2568. other than negatives so far working for other numbers .

Comment: Also Accrued:106.325 and Used:87.885  remaining returns 18.66 instead of 18h.26m

Comment: thank you so much satishcse I have been testing since yesterday and it works like a charm.

Comment: I changed decimal(9,2) to decimal(9,4) and it seems to be working, please try.

Comment: I have been testing and it fails on any decimal ends with 33 like (0.0333) and (0.5333). I am trying to change it but still not working. could you help me on this  satishcse?

Comment: I have added the tests in the answer using rounded values, please check if that's working.

Comment: so for working fine i need to test more with other numbers thank you so much  satishcse. If I little longer do calculations and look at numbers I will pass out soon :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to use seconds.  So try this:

```
select cast(dateadd(second, @Remaining*60*60, 0) as time)
```

This gives the result as a time data type.  Note that this type is limited to 24 hours.

Comment: I need to use decimal to accumulate all accrued hours like136.89 accrued and 129.89 used.

Comment: @JOZO . . . Then you cannot represent the amount using `time` in SQL Server.